# Working with SQLite as with SQL Server(on iPhone)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I'm newbie on IOS programming, so I have a question -- 
what's faster: create request to SQLite for each screen's openning on iPhone OR create one request and then sort result by Objective-C?
example: I have a screen with data and three buttons there.
first sorts and groups data by priority(it's a field of each records), second - by date, third - by author. So, what is getting result faster? If I send 3 requests to SQLite with specific predicates in NSFetchedRequest OR get result once and then sort it by my needs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using core data (which you seem to be doing if you are using predicates) then you can keep doing that since core data keeps entities in memory as well.

Comment: Yep. I mean, I'm working with SQLite via CoreData. So, if i send 3 same requests, only different by "order" statements, CoreData gets data from DB once and later uses cache?

Comment: Yes, the whole point of using core data is not to have to worry about this.